# Next.js Vercel Deployment Error, digest: '3619429646', An error occurred in the Server Components render

Tags: vercel, next.js13

My Next.js app is working perfectly fine in local environment. Even when I'm deploying the app, it doesn't show any error and getting perfectly deployed. But after deployment I can't see anything but a blank white page.

`[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] { digest: '3619429646' }`

This is the error, and I checked all my environment variables are in place.

If anyone can help me figure this out, I'll be highly thankful

Comment: Did you look at your logs?

Comment: Here's all I get from the logs:
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] { digest: '3619429646' }

Comment: The logs are available in your project console on vercel.